# How can I remove an html element and it's contents using RegEx

Tags: php, regex

I have a div id like to remove from an output which looks like

```
<div id="ithis" class="cthis">Content here which includes other elements etc..) </div>
```

How can I remove this div and everything within it using PHP and regex?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you further elaborate? Is this in the form of a string?

Comment: do you know the id name and/or class name? Or is there any distinct identifiers of the id and/or class so that you don't remove all divs falling into that description? Or do you want to remove all divs and their content?

Answer (score 13):

The simple answer is that you don't. You use one of PHP's many HTML parsers instead. Regexes are a flaky and error-prone way of manipulating HTML.

That being said you can do this:

```
$html = preg_replace('!<div\s+id="ithis"\s+class="cthis">.*?</div>!is', '', $html);
```

But **many** things can wrong with this. For example, if that contains a div:

```
<div id="ithis" class="cthis">Content here which <div>includes</div> other elements etc..) </div>
```

you'll end up with:

```
 other elements etc..) </div>
```

as the regex will stop at the first `</div>`. And no there's nothing you can really do to solve this problem (with regular expressions) consistently.

Done with a parser it looks more like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$element = $doc->getElementById('ithis');
$element->parentNode->removeChild($element);
$html = $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: +1.  It's worth commenting that (A) If the the element does not exist, then `$element` is `NULL` and the `->removeChild()` command will fail with a fatal error, and (B) you can / may want to use the `@` to cause the `->loadHTML()` to silence any notices about malformed HTML: `@$doc->loadHTML($html);`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about PHP, but you can replace `/<id.*?<\/id[^>]*>/` with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side, and the output is coming from the server. Can't you just not output it? Or are you trying to hide it? If so, in a stylesheet, just say `#ithis {display:none}`.

If the string is a return from some function in PHP that you haven't written AND you don't want to muck with that code, you have to write a very difficult regex to account for nested div's, varying syntax in the output, etc. I'd recommend using some parser (perhaps this [Zend Framework component](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.dom.query.html#zend.dom.query.methods)) to help you out. I've used it a few times for something similar. Although if you're not familiar with ZF at all, you may want to try something else.