# Use PHP to locate all elements with a class that starts with "enddate-"?

Tags: php, html, parsing

Thanks in advance for accommodating my glaring PHP limitations.

Consider this HTML:

```
<div class="story first enddate-2011-04-21">
  <h3>misc HTML content</h3> 
  ...
</div>

<div class="sparkly enddate-2014-01-01">
  <p>blah blah blah</p> 
  ...
</div>
```

How can I use PHP to identify all elements in an HTML doc with a class that starts with "enddate-" ?

Why I'd like to know: I want to use PHP (bx it's server-side) to locate all such elements, as in both divs above; then grab (and validate) the implied date info, and, if today's date is after the end date, cause that element and its inner contents to NOT be displayed on the served web page (so, in the above, remove all evidence of the first div now but leave the second one visible until 2014).

I found some advice [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114916/how-can-i-remove-an-html-element-and-its-contents-using-regex) about using a PHP HTML parser to locate elements with a specific ID, as in:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$element = $doc->getElementById('ithis');
$element->parentNode->removeChild($element);
$html = $doc->saveHTML();
```

Can this be modified to look for "*class* that *starts with* 'enddate' "?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could do this using XPath.

Something like this should work:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($domdocument);
$elements = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, 'enddate-')]");
```

(The xpath query is untested)

Comment: Check out: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/xpath_syntax.asp). Looks like '//*[@class='enddate-*']`, but that is untested.

Comment: If you use the attribute directly like you propose, it will only work when the class matches your pattern - thus it would need to start with enddate- for it to match. The contains function can be used to check for substrings

Comment: Thanks much! I'll play with that.

Comment: So if I read you correctly: If, as in the sample HTML, a class has other values before enddate (class="sparkly enddate-2014-01-01") this instance would not be found?

Comment: @ErikJ, without using the contains function, yes.