# Integrating full tumblr page into website

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, tumblr

I'm currently using this code:

> $blog= file_get_contents("http://powback.tumblr.com/post/" . $post);
>   echo $blog;

And it works. But tumblr has added a script that activates each time you enter a password-field. So my question is:

Can i remove certain parts with "file_get_contents"? 
Or just remove everything above 
anything will work! 
Thank you for your help!

(could i possibly kill a whole div so it wont load at all?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this, assuming the div you are trying to remove has a specific id and/or class:

```
$blog= file_get_contents("http://powback.tumblr.com/post/" . $post); 
$blog = preg_replace('!<div\s+id="div-id"\s+class="div-class">.*?</div>!is', '', $blog);
echo $blog;
```

The post I found this in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114916/how-can-i-remove-an-html-element-and-its-contents-using-regex) notes that if there is a nested div, this will fail.

Regardless, preg_replace or regex is your best bet here.