# Php Remove div in html with a certain class name with regex

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-replace

I have some html to parse which contains multiple divs, tags, links and so on. I want to remove via PHP all the divs with a specific class name: "hide" (even if the div has multiple class names it must work).

e.g.

`<div class="hide">somecontents, some tags, some subdivs</div>`

but also

`<div class="row background upperdiv hide green">somecontents, some tags, some subdivs</div>`

I've tried this regex:

```
$replacediv = "/(<div[^>]*class=\"(.*?)hide(.*?)\"[^>]*>*.*<\/div>)/i";
$response = preg_replace($replacediv, '', $response);
```

But it doesn't work! Where am I wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove an html element and it's contents using RegEx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114916/how-can-i-remove-an-html-element-and-its-contents-using-regex)

Comment: you wrote "/(<dv[^>]* 
it should be "/(<div[^>]*

Comment: sorry i meant div ( in the script is written correctly but it doesnt work )

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex (but if div contains another divs you may have problems):

```
$replacediv = '/<div[^>]+class="[^>]*hide[^>]*"[^>]*>.*?<\/div>/i';
$response = preg_replace($replacediv, '', $response);
```

Comment: does not work for me sorry. Even if i have no other div inside