# Remove a div with ID from the_content WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I was trying to remove a div having some ID from the_content WordPress.
I am trying to achieve something like this

```
jQuery( "#some_id" ).remove();
```

but on server side,

I don't have a clue how I can do this on server side within the_content filter hook.

This is something I like to achieve,

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter', 20 );
function my_the_content_filter( $content ) {


    $content.find('#some_id').remove();


    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Something like this,

Comment: add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter', 20 );
function my_the_content_filter( $content ) {


    $content.find('#some_id').remove();
 
 
    return $content;
}

Comment: js code inside php ????

Comment: that's just example, I don't know how to do it in php, I used JS/jQuery to clarify my purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is the answer for your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1114925/7335278

In your case this would look like:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter', 20 );
function my_the_content_filter( $content ) {


    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($content);
    $element = $doc->getElementById('some_id');
    $element->parentNode->removeChild($element);
    $content = $doc->saveHTML();


    return $content;
}
```

hth, let us know if this will work.
cheers, joel

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the previous answer.
I saw to late that what I answered was not what you were after.

Here something that might work.

```
$str = "<html><head></head><body><span id='remove_this'>This is one 
text</span><br /><span>this is a text after that</span></body></html>";

$id_pos =  strpos($str, 'remove_this');

$tmp_str = substr($str, ($id_pos-10), (strpos(substr($str, ($id_pos-10)), '</span>' )+7));

$str = str_replace($tmp_str, '', $str);

echo $str;
```

in the example above I start with searching for where the id is located in the string.
Than I do a substring function to get the start of the html element, in this case being the span.
Than in the same substring call I search for the first closing span tag and add 7 to the position to include the closing span tag.

than I replace the result of the substring in the original string and you get the result you are looking for.

I know there are always better ways but this is one :)

NOTE: This example of mine does use set amount of distance between the id position and the start of the tag as it directly after the start.
So there are most likely much better ways to get to the first instance of the `<` in php but I don't know it yet.

Hope this might get you a bit further.
I could also have gone into regular expressions but this is easier although all but the best way.
Regular expressions on the other hand are a lot more complex and I'm not really familiar with that stuff.

Cheers
and again sorry for the wrong answer at first.

Comment: I want to remove then entire dive (including it's content, may contain a lot of nested divs as well), not only remove the ID from a dive.

Comment: I just edited the answer. Sorry for the wrong answer at first. I did a quick test with this function but i know it is all but the best way. but for a quick fix this could possibly help you out. Otherwise I hope the other answers will help you/ have a good one :)

Answer (score 0):

The code is not tested. Just wrote for you... check this code... if this gives any syntactical error plz fix and let me know. But inside the content hook HTML/jsscripts are not running so you can try something like the following --

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter', 20 );
function my_the_content_filter( $content ) {


   $content = preg_replace("(<([a-z]+id=\"some_id\")>.*?</\\1>)is","",$content);


    return $content;
}
```